# Use of generics supertype in arrays

Tags: swift, generics

I have a question concerning generics in Swift. Why isn't this possible?

```
class GenerifiedClass<T> {
    func doSomething(thing: T) {
        print("doing something with \(thing)")
    }
}

class SuperType {}
class TypeA: SuperType {}
class TypeB: SuperType {}
class TypeC: SuperType {}

let a = GenerifiedClass<TypeA>()
let b = GenerifiedClass<TypeB>()
let c = GenerifiedClass<TypeC>()

let array: [GenerifiedClass<SuperType>] = [a, b, c]   // compile error
```

To clarify my question: why can't I type my array as `[GenerifiedClass<SuperType>]`? I kind of know why, because in Java for example this would also not be possible. But at least in Java there is syntax to solve this:

```
List<? extends SuperType> list = new ArrayList<>()
```

Is there an equivalent in Swift to `<? extends SuperType>` in Java?

Comment: I don't know the answer,  but the cast `a as! GenerifiedClass<SuperType>` fails, so probably the problem is that you cannot convert generics this way.

Comment: hmm ... I get the feeling generics in Swift need a lot more work to be usable. Every time I try something with generics I end up bumping against something like this. I don't get it, why did they drop the ball here while the rest of the language is totally awesome?

Comment: Hopefully these glitches will be improved in Swift 3.0 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to covariance of generics in Swift. Basically `GenerifiedClass<SuperType>` is not a superclass of `GenerifiedClass<TypeA>`, but is merely a sibling class, and this is why you cannot use it where you'd use polymorphism.

To answer the `extends` question, yes this is possible also in Swift:

```
class SuperType {}
class TypeA: SuperType {}
class TypeB: SuperType {}
class TypeC: SuperType {}

let a = TypeA()
let b = TypeB()
let c = TypeC()

let array: Array<SuperType> = [a, b, c]
```

,or

```
let array: [SuperType] = [a, b, c]
```

Comment: @TomvanZummeren just realised I didn't answered the second question, just updated my answer